# Copy button in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Pretty new to VBA and trying to create a reusable form with a copy and clear button. I was able to create a clear button but am having trouble with the copy button. Is there a way to copy the text in the 5 text boxes and the label of each text box so that I can paste it in the same format?

i.e
Details:
Text

Issue:
Text

Resolution:
Text

Notes/Research:
Text

Other:
text

[Form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEe6h.png)

```
Dim cc As ContentControl

Sub ResetForm()
    TextBox1 = ""
    TextBox2 = ""
    TextBox3 = ""
    TextBox4 = ""
    TextBox5 = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Click()
Form_clear = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question")
    If Form_clear = 6 Then
        Call ResetForm
    Else
        Form_clear = 7
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Copy_Click()
    Dim text1 As String


End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your title to something that is more than just *Copy Button* and then repeating information that is already in the tags twice. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your current title doesn't provide anything other than useless repeating of the tag info. Thanks.

Comment: You can populate the clipboard with text, but where do you need to be able to paste it?  It's unclear what you mean by "in the same format".

Comment: @TimWilliams paste it anywhere. Let’s say a word document. I just want it to be in the same format. Line by line.

Comment: 5 separate paragraphs?

Comment: @TimWilliams just like the part under i.e. I want the word above the text box with the text in the text box with a space in between each 5 parts. - details, text in text box, and then a space. Issue, text in text box, and then space. Resolution, text in text box, and then space. So on and so on.

Comment: `text1 = "Details:" & vbcrlf & Textbox1 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Issue:" & Textbox2 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & etc etc`

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you! I’ll try it out tomorrow morning and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
text1 = "Details:" & vbcrlf & Textbox1 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
        "Issue:" & vbcrlf & Textbox2 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
        "Resolution:" & vbcrlf & Textbox3 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
        "Notes/Research:" & vbcrlf & Textbox3 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
        "Other:" & vbcrlf & Textbox5
```

or a bit less cluttered:

```vb
text1 = Join(Array("Details:", Textbox1, vbCrLf, _
                   "Issue:", Textbox2, vbCrLf, _
                   "Resolution:", Textbox3, vbCrLf, _
                   "Notes/Research:", Textbox3, vbCrLf, _
                   "Other:", Textbox5), vbCrLf)
```